# Preact error: "objects are not valid as a child. Encountered an object with the keys {}" when using async await in root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, preact, preact-router

I'm using Preact for the first time.

I simply created a new project with preact-cli and this default template: https://github.com/preactjs-templates/default.

In `app.js` I'm trying to use this code:

```js
import { Router } from 'preact-router';

import Header from './header';
import Home from '../routes/home';
import Profile from '../routes/profile';

// I added this function
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const App = async () => { // I added "async" and the "{" in this line
  await sleep(3000) // I added this line

  return ( // I added this line
    <div id="app">
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Home path="/" />
        <Profile path="/profile/" user="me" />
        <Profile path="/profile/:user" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
} // I added this line

export default App;
```

But unfortunately browser's gives me error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a child. Encountered an object with the keys {}.
```

**Why?**

It works if I do not use `async/await`.

Comment: Ultimately unrelated to this solution, but for others whose googling lands on this question, note that you could also run into this error if you're using [htm rendering](https://github.com/developit/htm) instead of JSX and stupidly leave the `${}` off of your tag type. So `<MyComponent></MyComponent>` can give the error. `<${MyComponent}></MyComponent>` fixes it. /sigh The accepted answer did clue me in, fwiw: "_Our debug addon... will print this error whenever an invalid object is passed as a child that doesn't match the expected return type_". Quite right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work on Preact.*

Our debug addon (`preact/debug`) will print this error whenever an invalid object is passed as a child that doesn't match the expected return type of `h/createElement`, usually called `vnode`:

```
const invalidVNode = { foo: 123 };
<div>{invalidVNode}</div>
```

In your case your component function returns a `Promise` which is an object in JavaScript. When Preact renders that component the render function will NOT return a `vnode`, but a Promise instead. That's why the error occurs.

Which poses the question:

### How to do async initialization?

Once triggered, the render process in Preact is always synchronous. A component that returns a `Promise` breaks that contract. The reason it is that way is because you usually want to show at least something, like a spinner, to the user, while the asynchronous initialization is happening. A real world scenario for that would be fetching data via the network for example.

```
import { useEffect } from "preact/hooks";

const App = () => {
  // useEffect Hook is perfect for any sort of initialization code.
  // The second parameter is for checking when the effect should re-run.
  // We only want to initialize once when the component is created so we
  // pass an empty array so that nothing will be dirty checked.
  useEffect(() => {
    doSometThingAsyncHere()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Home path="/" />
        <Profile path="/profile/" user="me" />
        <Profile path="/profile/:user" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reactjs is a component library. At the core it has a function like

```
React.createElement(component, props, ...children)
```

Here the first parameter is the component that you want to render.

When you are putting `await sleep(3000)` the function is not returning any valid children/html object rather it is returning an empty object.
that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Oh. You're right. Is there a way to fix this? I need to wait.

Comment: can you please share your use case why you need to wait before rendering anything ? Because you can return an empty <div></div>. if you are waiting for any particular condition to fulfill .

Comment: I need to initialize many javascript libraries before and then I use a component like: `<Root initialized={what I Initialized}>`.

Comment: My knowledge is limited but as far as i know there is no way to do exactly what you are trying to achieve. But you can use a loader before initializing your other libraries . In that case you can use a local state variable called ``` const [loaded , setLoaded] = useState=(false) ``` and after 3s you can set it to true. 

based on the value of loaded you can render your app or Loader.